# Visualize laserscan usig rviz

Tags: rviz, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to visualize a topic of type sensor_msgs/LaserScan using rviz? Currently it complains about not having any frame (which is true, I just have the scan data)... Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59881/visualize-laserscan-usig-rviz/) by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which laserdriver are you using? Normally every sensor message has a frame attached. (You can find out this frame by using `rostopic echo /scan -n 1 --noarr`)

If no transforms are published, rviz will not show that frame as a possibility in the `Fixed Frame` dropdown-menu. But if you just type in the frame-name by hand, rviz should be able to visualize your laserscan.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on 2013-04-03**:
I'm not sure what you're getting at, but i found this in the output: frame_id: '' The publishing node a bridge between another system and ROS so if something needs to be added I'm open to that. Thanks.

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-03**:
Have you written this bridging node yourself? The header of the message should contain a valid frame name/id (for example `laser`, try setting laserscan_msg->header.frame_id) and a timestamp.

**Comment by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on 2013-04-03**:
Sorry, I am kind of lost when it comes to visualization and the like. What is the simplest thing that could pass as a valid frame? At this point the scanner is just sitting on the desk with no odometry or maps available. Is it possible visualize the environment around a fixed scanner?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-04-03**:
Like i mentioned, `laser` would be a valid frame id. You can read this about the naming conventions for frames: http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/CoordinateFrameConventions#Naming

**Comment by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on 2013-04-03**:
Now I get it, and it works fine. Thank you!